# Hashing Equals only returns true

Tags: collections, dictionary, hashmap, equals, hashcode

Consider the sample code:

```
class EmployeeClass {
    int id;
    public EmployeeClass(int eid) {
        this.id=eid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return this.id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return true;
    }
}

public class HashcodeAndEquals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map=new HashMap();
        EmployeeClass e1=new EmployeeClass(1);
        map.put(e1, "Employee 1");                // line 1
        EmployeeClass e2=new EmployeeClass(2);
        map.put(e2, "Employee 2");
        EmployeeClass e3=new EmployeeClass(3);
        EmployeeClass e4=new EmployeeClass(1);   // line 2
        EmployeeClass e5=new EmployeeClass(1);
        map.put(e5, "Employee 5");                // line 3
        System.out.println("e1 -> "+map.get(e1)); 
        System.out.println("e2 -> "+map.get(e2));
        System.out.println("e3 -> "+map.get(e3));
        System.out.println("e4 -> "+map.get(e4)); // line 4
        System.out.println("e5 -> "+map.get(e5));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
e1 -> Employee 5
e2 -> Employee 2
e3 -> null
e4 -> Employee 5

e5 -> Employee 5
```

After line 1 runs, then line 3 override the value of `e1` but my equals method return true only. Also at line 4 we get the value of `e4` even though `equals` method only return true. Since `equals` method has no comparison only returns true, how put and get is working here. What is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: You could use a debugger and find out?

Comment: What are you surprised of? The keys e1, e4 and e5 are equivalent, so they point to the same value.

Comment: understood. must have used before asking. anyways gr8 help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're surprised that not all of them are Employee 5? Equals always returns true so e5 should have overwritten all of them, right?

A HashMap uses "buckets" behind the scenes. Let's say that there's only 2, to make it simple. A real HashMap has a lot more.

When you put an object into a HashMap, it looks at the hashCode first. (That's why it's called a HashMap.) Based on the hashCode, it chooses a bucket to store it in. For `e1`, the hashCode is 1, so it would choose bucket 1. For `e2`, it's 2, so that goes into bucket 2. The hashCode for `e3` is 3, but there's only 2 buckets, so it will go into bucket 3 modulo 2, which is 1. `e4` goes into bucket 2 for the same reason, and `e5` is back in 1.

Note that I'm simplifying here extremely; in reality the process is a little more complex, but this should be enough to explain things.

So we have the following buckets:

```
bucket 1 | bucket 2
e5       | e4
e3       | e2
e1       |
```

So now it's time to retrieve values. When I retrieve `e1`, the hashCode is still 1, so it looks in bucket 1. There, it picks the first object which `equals` `e1`, which is `e5`: the last object you put in, is the first that gets out, apparently. `e2` directs to bucket 2, so in this example case, you would get `e4` as a result.

In your case, you did never actually put `e3` and `e4` into the HashMap. But because `e3`'s hashCode directs to bucket 1, and it's equal to `e5`, when you look up `e3` you still get `e5` even though it's not actually there.

As I said, this is an extreme simplification of things. In a real HashMap, there's a lot more than 2 buckets. So in your case, `e3` has a hashcode that directs to an empty bucket, and the hashCodes for `e1`, `e4` and `e5` apparently all direct to the same bucket.

This is why it's important, when you write hashCode, to give it a good "distribution". If you always return 42, all objects would always go into the same bucket, which would turn your HashMap into essentially a very awkward ArrayList. You'd lose al the performance benefits that HashMap gives you.